# Symbols for contradiction for a proof by contradiction?

Tags: support, mathjax

Are there symbols for contradiction for a proof by contradiction? 
I tried $\lightning, \Lightning$.

To clarify, there's no code for lightning? I believed it'd be shorter than `\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow`

Answer (score 8):

`\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow` gives $\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$. There's a good argument that words are better, though.

Comment: I would write "For the purpose of deriving a contradiction suppose that blah, blah." Then I would end with "This is the desired contradiction." Perhaps the latter statement might include equation numbers.

Comment: thanks. why are words better?

Comment: @Tucker: Because everybody understands "Contradiction!" whereas notation depends on convention much more than words.

Comment: And I don't think any particular convention is widespread; the symbol I drew above (or maybe it was $\rightarrow\!\leftarrow$) was introduced to me by one of my professors, but I don't think I've ever seen it in a book. Similarly, I don't think I've ever seen the `\lightning` symbol you mention before. As Asaf said, everyone knows "contradiction".

Comment: Words are better, yes.  Except when you have to write fast, and do not expect strangers to read the result.  The same comment applies to a lot of other symbolism.  Write "and" instead of writing $\wedge$.  Write "if...then" instead of writing $\Longrightarrow$.